# MongoDB: Buscar por fecha en PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, date

Tengo una colección en MongoDB de 45 millones de registros (En realidad teníamos una base de datos en SQL Server, pero esta ya empieza a tener problemas, así que nos estamos pasando a Mongo y consultamos la información usando PHP. La estructura de los documentos es la siguiente:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("57ed4ec22ca3b409d8d140bf"), 
"fecges" : ISODate("2015-11-16T05:00:00.000+0000"), 
"horges" : "16:28:06", 
"telefono" : "7958279", 
"feccomp" : ISODate("1900-01-01T05:00:00.000+0000"), 
"observacion_gs" : "Esta es una observacion", 
"rango_hora" : "16:00-16:59", 
"inicio_gestion" : ISODate("2015-11-16T21:22:56.000+0000"), 
"fin_gestion" : ISODate("2015-11-16T21:28:06.000+0000"), 
"usuario" : "NOMBRE DE USUARIO", 
"RowID" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

Necesito saber como hacer lo siguiente usando PHP:

- Como consultar todos los registros del campo "fecges" de una fecha específica (por ejemplo la que figura en este ejemplo: 2015-11-16)
- Necesito saber cuales son los registros cuyo "inicio_gestion" y "fin_gestion" estén en el rango indicado (Ej: inicio_gestion: 2015-11-16, y fin_gestion: 2015-11-18).

He usado el siguiente código, pero me sale un error que no encuentro (error de sintaxis "{"):

```
$db.r_gestiones.find({ "inicio_gestion": {'$gt': new MongoDate("2015-11-16"), '$gte': new MongoDate("2015-11-16") }});
```

Este código me devuelve demasiados resultados:

```
$db = $conn->r_gestiones;
$coleccion = $db->r_gestiones;
$consulta = array( "inicio_gestion"=>array('$gt'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 00:00:00"))));
$cursor = $coleccion->find( $consulta );
```

Y la modificación del código anterior me devuelve mucha información también:

```
$db = $conn->r_gestiones;
$coleccion = $db->r_gestiones;
$consulta = array( "inicio_gestion"=>array('$gt'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 00:00:00")), '$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 23:59:59"))));
$cursor = $coleccion->find( $consulta );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno respondo mi propia pregunta:

Lo que ocurre es que al devolver mi consulta demasiados documentos, PHP excede el límite de memoria y me envía a error. Lo que hice para solventar este problema y ver resultados fue usar "limit" de la siguiente manera:

```
$db = $conn->r_gestiones;
$coleccion = $db->r_gestiones;
$consulta = array( "inicio_gestion"=>array('$gt'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 00:00:00")), '$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 23:59:59"))));
$cursor = $coleccion->find( $consulta )->limit(10);
```

De esta forma solo estoy obteniendo los diez primeros registros, solucionando así mi problema. Espero este código les sea de utilidad.

Aquí tiene un [link](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/26903435041/mongodb-for-the-php-mind-part-2) hacia más información sobre cómo usar "limit"

Gracias.

Comment: De hecho, es lo que deberías hacer siempre. Ahorras memoria y ancho de banda. La técnica se llama Lazy Loading.

Answer (score 0):

El segundo operador de tu consulta, `$gte`, significa `greater than or equal`, luego es casi lo mismo que `$gt`. Tu consulta devuelve todos los registros posteriores a las **23:59** de ese día. Un año y medio de registros.

Prueba con el operador `$lte` (less than or equal) para acotar los resultados a los registros previos a las **23:59** de la fecha que indicas

Tu consulta quedaría de la forma:

```
$consulta = [
    "inicio_gestion"=>[
        '$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 00:00:00")), 
        '$lte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 23:59:59"))
     ]
];
```

Eso trae todas las tareas empezadas el día 2015-11-16.

Si además quieres cruzarlo con los trabajos que terminaron antes del final de ese día:

```
$consulta = [
  '$and' => [
    "inicio_gestion"=>[
        '$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 00:00:00")), 
        '$lte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 23:59:59"))
    ],
    "fin_gestion"=>[
        '$lte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-16 23:59:59"))
    ]
  ]
];
```

En este segundo caso, el operador `$lte` en la primera parte de la query es redundante: si *terminó* antes de la medianoche del 16 de noviembre, es implícito que *comenzó* antes de la medianoche del 16 de noviembre.